# how to convert bytearray to an object in HBase

Tags: hbase

I'm learning HBase by practising. I got how to convert a byte array from a customWritableObject. I have created a byte array using

byte[] byteArray =   WritableUtils.toByteArray(customWritableObject);

Not able to get how to convert it back to customWritableObejct from byteArray.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that by serializing the object in the hbase column value and then again deserializing  it and then type casting to the corresponding Class.

For more details, please see the blog -

http://xtremideas.blogspot.in/2013/04/how-to-store-complex-class-object-in.html

Thanks